# Show that $U(x+k,t+h)$ is a solution to the wave equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

So the wave equation:

$$U_{tt}-c^2U_{xx}=0.$$

---

This is as far as I've gotten so far:

---

Let $a:=x+k, b:=t+h$, then by chain rule

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}.
\end{equation}
Using the alternate notation for partial derivatives, we have
\begin{equation}
    U_x=U_a(1)+U_b(0)=U_a,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    U_t=U_a(0)+U_b(1)=U_b.
\end{equation}
Now, since we require a second derivative, we must differentiate (31) and (32) once again. We have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\Big)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\Big),
\end{equation}
or equivalently, by the product rule
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}\Big)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\Big)+
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\Big)+\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\Big),
\end{equation}

however it then just unravels into a big mess, and would like a pointer or two on how to proceed from here.

---

OK, so we have

$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}=1, \frac{\partial b}{\partial x}=0, \frac{\partial a}{\partial t}=0, \frac{\partial b}{\partial t}=1,$$

then, our second derivative equation simplifies to

\begin{equation}
U_{xx}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\Big),
\end{equation}

---

using the fact that $U_x=U_a$ as done above, we can say $$U_{xx}=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}=U_{aa}.$$

---

Similarly, for $U_{tt}$
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}\Big)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}\Big),
\end{equation}
or equivalently, by the product rule
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}\Big)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial a}\Big)+
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}\Big)+\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}\Big),
\end{equation}
which simplifies to
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial U}{\partial b},
\end{equation}
now, using the relation established with our first order derivatives, we get
\begin{equation}
    U_{tt}=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\frac{\partial U}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial b^2}=U_{bb}.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
    U_{tt}-c^2U_{xx}=0 \Rightarrow U_{bb}-c^2U_{aa}=0,
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: I think you'll get some mileage by computing $\partial a/\partial x$, $\partial b/\partial x$< $\partial a/\partial t$, and $\partial b/\partial t$, and then substituting those into your equation.

Comment: @Neal So I've done that and simplified it a touch. Does everything seem reasonable so far?

Comment: It looks fine. You just need to go one step further, show that $U_{xx}=U_{aa}$

Comment: The last step will be something like using $U_{aa} - c^2U_{bb} = 0$.

Comment: Everything fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good.

I'd propose a couple of minor simplifications/clarifications:
First, the differential equation is really, 
$$ (\mbox{second derivative in time}) - c^2 (\mbox{second derivative in space}) = 0 $$
So by the definition of $a$ and $b$, we have $U_{bb} - c^2 U_{aa} = 0$.

Second, to avoid confusion, consider renaming $U(x+k, t+h)$ to be something like $F$. This will simplify your notation -- see below. Your goal is now to show that $F_{tt} - c^2 F_{xx} = 0$.

Third, I'd suggest simplifying your derivatives each step of the differentiation. That will make it easier to track. For example:
$$ F_x = U_aa_x + U_bb_x = U_a $$
and so 
$$ F_{xx} = (F_x)_x = (U_a)_x = U_{aa}a_x + U_{ab}b_x = U_{aa} $$
and similarly with differentiation in time:
$$ F_t = U_aa_t + U_bb_t = U_b,\ \ F_{tt} = (F_t)_t = (U_b)_t = U_{ba}a_t + U_{bb}b_t = U_{bb} $$

The denouement is simply
$$ F_{xx} - c^2 F_{tt} = U_{aa} - c^2 U_{bb} = 0. $$

Comment: Ah yes, I had a feeling my notation was very confusing and was a bit bogged down with it while trying to compute all the  required derivatives. Also, simplifying it each step again makes it a lot better to read. Thank you for your assistance though, much appreciated!